# Why is there a "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index" error in Pandas version 2.0.0 only

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

Complete newb here, for asking questions on this platform as well as python development.

I was given a script and there is a line of code that works with Pandas 1.4.4, but not Pandas 2.0.0.

The line of code is:

```
CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum())
```

When I force install pandas v1.4.4, the script completes without error.

When using Pandas 2.0.0, I get:

```
"TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"
```

I created a virtual environment and installed Pandas v1.4.4.  This is the version that is in the Ananconda distribution I was originally using to run this script in a Jupyter notebook.

When I tried using VSCode and installed Pandas, version 2.0.0 was installed.   Then the error started.

I know enough that certain package versions are necessary and that's the point of virtual environments.

Just wondering if I should post an issue on github for this.   I found similar looking issue posts, but thought they may be for older (than 1.4.4) pandas versions.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't use `apply`+`cumsum`. You can directly use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].cumsum()
```

Unlike `apply`, this will handle the index differently, leaving it unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly. However if you try to set the result as a new column, it raises an exception because the index are not aligned:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'UNIT_NUM': list('1112222'), 'COST': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(df)

# Output
```

What it works:

```
CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum())
0     1
1     3
2     6
3     1
4     3
5     6
6    10
Name: COST, dtype: int64
```

What it doesn't work:

```
CLEANCPM['cumsum'] = CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum())
...
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

How to fix this (use [`group_keys=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#using-group-keys-with-transformers-in-dataframegroupby-apply-and-seriesgroupby-apply) **Changed in version 1.5.0**):

```
CLEANCPM['cumsum'] = CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'], group_keys=False)['COST'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum())
  UNIT_NUM  COST  cumsum
0        1     1       1
1        1     2       3
2        1     3       6
3        2     1       1
4        2     2       3
5        2     3       6
6        2     4      10

# OR using droplevel
CLEANCPM['cumsum'] = CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].apply(lambda x:x.cumsum()).droplevel(0)
  UNIT_NUM  COST  cumsum
0        1     1       1
1        1     2       3
2        1     3       6
3        2     1       1
4        2     2       3
5        2     3       6
6        2     4      10
```

What is better, @mozway's answer:

```
CLEANCPM['cumsum'] = CLEANCPM.groupby(['UNIT_NUM'])['COST'].cumsum()
  UNIT_NUM  COST  cumsum
0        1     1       1
1        1     2       3
2        1     3       6
3        2     1       1
4        2     2       3
5        2     3       6
6        2     4      10
```